# Integrating Plot into Svelte

Tags: plot, svelte, sveltekit, observablehq

How to integrate [@observablehq/plot](https://github.com/observablehq/plot) in Svelte?

Below is the code, currently working for me, is there a better way to integrate?

```html
<script>
import * as Plot from "@observablehq/plot";

export function myplot(node) {
  node.appendChild(
    Plot.plot({x: {domain: [100, 0]}, grid: true})
  )
}
</script>


<div use:myplot></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For external components and libraries you have to do something like this. That is a reasonable approach; you can encapsulate the integration in a separate component to make its usage as convenient as you want.

E.g. the most basic approach is to expose all the options as a component property:

```html
<script>
    import * as Plot from "@observablehq/plot";
    
    export let options;

    function myplot(node) {
        node.appendChild(
            Plot.plot(options)
        )
    }
</script>


{#key options}
    <div use:myplot {...$$restProps}></div>
{/key}
```

The `{#key}` block makes the plot re-render when the `options` change.

Usage:

```html
<script>
  import Plot from './Plot.svelte'
</script>

<Plot options={{ x: { domain: [100, 0] }, grid: true }} />
```

If you need events and other interactivity that can be exposed as needed.

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/d35d543cf0014f0fa850b942b4d76f2b?version=3.47.0)

Comment: Thank you. I tried to move the numbers inside `domain` to variables and introduced a button to change the values. The values change on click but `<Plot />` is not picking it up.